# JavaScript - Bug or am I Blind?

Tags: javascript, onclick

Why this code doesn't work? I've been trying to see what is the problem, but can't figure it out!

```
<script>
function change()
{
document.getElementByID("text").innerHTML=Date();
}
</script>
<div id="text">Here is some text</div>
<button type="button" onclick="change()">OK?</button>
```

But this code works:

```
<script>
function displayDate()
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Date();
}
</script>
<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
<div id="demo">This is a paragraph.</div>

<button type="button" onclick="displayDate()">Display Date</button>
```

What is wrong with the 1st code?

Comment: `innerHtml` maybe? Should be `innerHTML` I guess.

Comment: @AfonsoMatos — Not the **only** problem. Read your JavaScript error console.

Comment: And `getElementByID` should be `...ById`. Please use your developer console.

Comment: @AfonsoMatos: Basic steps to take before asking a question in JavaScript and avoid downvotes: 1. Validate syntax at http://www.jshint.com/, 2. Debug code in console F12 and write down any errors, 3. If you don't understand something check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) _first_ 4. Post live demo at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @elclanrs There should be some kind of filter when you are posting a question and it's tagged with a browser technology like JavaScript or jQuery, and possibly when you're under a certain number of rep, that warns the OP of these kinds of thing; hopefully preventing several of these types of questions. I know you have no power over this, I just thought I'd chime in

Answer (score 3):

innerHtml vs innerHTML (capitalization)

Comment: Also `document.getElementByID` should be `document.getElementById`

Comment: Ow, thank you Zenith, that was the problem

Comment: @AfonsoMatos that was one of your problems...

Comment: @AfonsoMatos Did you edit your question and change the `innerHtml` typo?

Answer (score 3):

You have a capital `ID` in `document.getElementById` your first example. It should be a lowercase `Id`